# Класс не становится active в одном из выпадающих пунктов меню

Tags: php, css, yii2, dropdown

У меня в приложении на Yii2 в виджете Nav несколько пунктов меню с выпадающими подпунктами и подпункты к одному подгружается с базы даных. Так вот, именно в этом пункте меню для li выбраного подпункта не проставляется класс active, хотя в остальных пунктах меню всё работает нормально.
Не понимаю в чём дело, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может быть из-за того, что подменю у вас грузится динамически из базы через Ajax, а класс выставляется при отрисовке страницы

Comment: Я немного поэкспериментировала и узнала, что это всё из-за ссылок вида http://boarding-school/static-pages/page?id=3
То есть дело либо в ?, либо в =
Когда ссылка такого вида http://boarding-school/news-events/index-news, то всё работает.
Однако я не знаю, что делать, потому что как же мне передавать какую страницу подгружать, если не по id?

Comment: Поменяла вид ссылки на http://boarding-school/static-pages/page/4, всё равно не работает. Может дело в количестве вложений?

Comment: Трудно судить. Обновите ответ, и добавьте код NavBar, код конкретного action и конфиг urlManager